# Session not created error with physical device

Tags: appium-ios

I've been trying to run automated tests with Appium, they are already running in physical devices, but I get the error: [WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"value":{"error":"session not created","message":"'capabilities' is mandatory to create a new session"}

I've gone through the configuration guide and the webDriverAgent seems to be running correctly in the device, when I make a request to the webdriveragent running on the device I get the response:

```
[WD Proxy] Determined that the downstream protocol for proxy is W3C
[XCUITest] WebDriverAgent information:
[XCUITest] {
[XCUITest]   "message": "WebDriverAgent is ready to accept commands",
[XCUITest]   "state": "success",
```

However, when Appium makes the request to create a new WDA session, receives the following response:

```
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"value":{"error":"session not created","message":"'capabilities' is mandatory to create a new session"},"sessionId":"595F87C8-0564-4B75-94B4-7D67BA0AF382"}
```

Using these capabilities

```
'app': app,
'bundleId' : bundle_id,
'platformName': platform_name,
'automationName': automation_name,
'platformVersion': platform_version,
'deviceName': device_name,
'udid': udid,
'xcodeOrgId': xcode_org_id,
'xcodeSigningId': xcode_signing_id,
'newCommandTimeout': new_command_timeout,
'updatedWDABundleId': updated_WDA_Bundle_Id,
'agentPath': "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj",
'bootstrapPath': "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent"
```

Is there anything else I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if these capabilities are actually required:

```
'updatedWDABundleId': updated_WDA_Bundle_Id,
'agentPath': "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj",
'bootstrapPath': "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent"
```

try removing them, also in my tests i have noticed that it is necessary to restart the appium server everytime you switch from real device to simulator.

Hope it helps